# Mvc 5 ajax display collection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have class :

```
public JsonResult refreshMap(int time)
{
    // Some code before

    List<User> lista = new List<User>();
    lista.Add(usr11);
    lista.Add(usr22);
    return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And view :

```
<div id="PersonList"></div>
<input type="radio" name="time" value="5">Last 5min  
<input type="radio" name="time" value="15">Last 15min
```

And the attached JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio[name="time"]').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Connection/refreshMap',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                time: $(':radio[name="time"]:checked').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $("#PersonList").append(value.Email);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I want do this : when i checked radio I use method and I get data from controller and I want display this collection. But my function in ajax doesn't work. But when I return in method refreshMap only one object: `[...] return Json(usr11, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

And if I change my ajax function like below, this work !

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio[name="time"]').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Connection/refreshMap',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { time: $(':radio[name="time"]:checked').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#PersonList").append(data.Email +"</br>");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Have you idea what I can repair it?

Comment: so this work or not ? WHere is exactly the problem in your code ?

Comment: Dosn't work when i display collection. Probably problem is in first ajax function which i paste.

Comment: Don't see the problem. This is the success function who don't work in the first and in the second yes ? You each is correct. What is the return of json ?

Comment: First don't work, second work.  Json is a data format

Comment: Please tell me what is the return of the json (the value !)

Comment: Doesn't work when json return collection (List<User>)
Work when json return one object (<User>)

Comment: So it isn't a js error but in your php. Check your code

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you return a collection (`List<User>`) then you need a loop (`$.each()`) to access each item in the collection (i.e. as per your first script) and if you a single `User` then you don't use a loop as per your second script.

Comment: I know. I checked and I return collection which have 3 elements. And this loop don't work;/

Comment: Ok work;p i had mistake in my controller

Thanks for all

Comment: Then you should delete this question - its of no use to anyone else and others may waste their time trying to give you answers to something which cannot be answered

Answer (score 0):

data comes wrapped in 'd', by using $each you seem to enter the data object but in the second one it does not 'project' the values.

i usually do `if(data.d){...}` just to make sure the data will not shortcircuit my code, or the absence of it to be concrete.

Will also look at what type is 'Email' and how it serialised.